# How can I list the files in other (non-current) directory?

Tags: directory, ls

If ls lists the content of the current directory, is there a similar command that list the content of a non current directory, without using cd?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After `ls` just type the path of the directory you want to list and you will get it. Imagine you are in your home directory but want to list `/etc`. Just run `ls /etc` and you will get it listed.

Answer (score 12):

`ls` will do this.

The syntax for `ls` is:

```
 ls flags file-or-directory-names
```

For what I'm calling **`file-or-directory-names`**, you can list files in the current directory, to have just certain files listed. For example, `ls -l foo bar` will list information on just `foo` and `bar` (in long form, as I've given the `-l` flag). `ls baz*go` will list all files whose names start with `baz` and end with `go` (if any).

But when you give a *directory name* to `ls`, it lists the contents of *that directory* instead of the current directory.

So, to list the contents of `/var/log`, you would simply run:

```
ls /var/log
```

If you give a *relative* path for the directory--that is, one that doesn't start with a `/`--then it will look for that directory inside the current directory (just as it looks for files). But it will still list the *contents* of the directory, as you want.

As a side note, sometimes you might find you don't want to list the *contents* of a directory, but just list the directory the same as a file would be listed. To do this, you can pass the `-d` flag. For example, this shows `/var/log` in long form (not its *contents*, but `/var/log` itself):

```
ls -ld /var/log
```

Comment: Very detailed. However, remember that `ls` is not responsible for expanding `baz*go` to all files that start with `baz` and end with `go` -- it's the shell that does this.

Comment: @krlmlr Right, `ls baz*go` is an example of `ls` receiving (potentially) multiple arguments for **`file-or-directory-names`** (and in this way is similar to `ls foo bar`).

Answer (score 0):

Having seen the accepted answer, I was still not satisfied. How did Daniel know the solution? You bet I have read the manpage myself and still couldn't figure out how.

The man page of `ls` reads:

> Description: List  information  about  the FILEs (the current directory by default)...

Nothing useful there. Then I checked POSIX Programmer's Manual:

> For each operand that names a file of type directory, ls shall write the names of files contained within the directory as well as any requested, associated information.

This line explains the behavior of the command in the accepted solution. The `FILE` operand of `ls` CAN be a directory, and `ls` will list the content of that directory. Exactly what the OP wanted. BUT the implementation on Linux may differ from the specification here. So we are on the right track but not there yet.

Then I searched for the manual of GNU `coreutils` package, which `ls` is a part of. Here is what I found:

> For non-option command-line arguments that are directories, by default ls lists the contents of directories ...

This explains it.

Comment: Almost certainly the responder knew the solution because they'd tried using  `ls` with directory names, or saw it used, or just knew about Unix philosophy ("everything is a file"), or copied the `dir` (MS-DOS) behaviour,  rather than poring over the coreutils manpage. You can feed `ls` a list of files, referencing a directory does that. The manpage says "FILEs". A directory is, essentially, a list of files.